# Ubuntu Server Wireless connection issue - replaced router but kept ESSID

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I have a ubuntu server 12.04 which was connected to my wireless network with no problem

I replaced the wireless router but kept the ESSID and password the same.

All other devices on network have connected correctly.

However the Ubuntu Server will not route correctly.

It will connect to the wifi router, and get a dhcp served IP address, however it will not route anything. I cannot ping the router from the server. the contents of /etc/resolve.conf are updated with the information from the router, (the host name has been served)

I know there is nothing wrong with the router or the server, or the wireless card etc.

I'm assuming there's some cached setting that associates the old router with the ESSID and causing the issue.

I've got a lot of other devices connected to the router, so don't want to change the name of the ESSID.

How do I fix this?

EDIT:
outputs (abbreviated as I've got no cut and paste)

```
netstat -rn:
Kernel IP Routing table
Dest        Gate        Gen            Flags     MSS Window     irtt     Iface
0.0.0.0     192.168.0.1 0.0.0.0.       UG          0 0          0        wlan0
192.168.0.0 0.0.0.0.    255.255.255.0  U           0 0          0        wlan0
```

Comment: What's the output of `netstat -rn` and `ifconfig wlan0`? (or whatever your wireless interface is)

Comment: no cut and paste for me. I'll update the answer with those. Suffice to say they look OK to me...

Comment: I'm afraid the output of ifconfig wlan0 is a bit of a nightmare to type out... but it basically says its got an IP address, the link is up, its received 5.5Mb of data its sent 426Kb, no dropped packets etc.  It looks fine. Is there a specific entry that might give you a clue?

Comment: That was the information I was looking for: It's received and sent data and hasn't dropped anything. What is the specific error you get from `ping 192.168.0.1` ? Is it "Destination not reachable", or "Request Timed out", or something else? Also, can you check the router settings for "AP Isolation"?

Comment: massively long hang and no response. So it's hanging as though its got no idea how to route. corrupt routing tables? How do I refresh those?

Comment: That's very strange... If there are routing issues, then it prints "Destination not reachable". Try `ping -W 2 -v -n 192.168.0.1`

Comment: can't find AP isolation on the router.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9359/discussion-between-darth-android-and-stevo)